# Integral of a product of even function and odd function

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I think it's true. if i'll multyply an even function with an odd function i will get an odd function. and we know that this equals to zero because the negetive and the positive cancel each other out.
Is it really that simple or am i missing a counter example ?

Comment: It really is that simple, if you already know that an integral of an odd function over $[-a,a]$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product of even function and odd function is odd function ($g(-x)=f_e(-x)f_0(-x)=f_e(x)\cdot (-f_e(x))=-f_e(x)f_0(x)=-g(x)$), then 
$$\int_{-a}^a g_o(x)dx=0$$