# Double integral with trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral

$$\iint_D (x^2y +y\sin(x^9)) dxdy,$$

where $ D={ (x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq 2, y> 0}$. In other words, a half circle disk above the x axis the the radius $\sqrt2$.

Unless I'm mistaken, this should give $$ \int_{-\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (yx^2+y\sin(x^9)) dy \right)dx$$

and, ultimately, $\displaystyle\int_{-\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+\sin(x^9)-\frac{x^2\sin(x^9)}{2}\right) dx$.

Here, I am stuck. I can't figure out how to integrate $\sin(x^9)$. Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: That's an odd function over a symmetric integral. Also, since $f(x):=x^2\sin(x^9)$ is a product of an odd and an even function, it's odd itself, so the same holds. The integral of those two is $0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does knowing a function as even or odd help in integration ??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438691/how-does-knowing-a-function-as-even-or-odd-help-in-integration) $$\\$$ [Integral of a product of even function and odd function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1728856/721644) $$\\$$ [Why is $\sin(x^3)$ odd?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625291/721644)

Comment: @Invisible That certainly gives the right result. Thanks! However, for similar integrals over a non-symmetrical area, like $\int_{0}^{1} ( \int_{\sqrt(x)}^{1} sin(\pi y^3)dy)dx$ it doesn't seem to help much. Are there similar tricks for that situation?

Comment: You can get rid of $f(x,y)=y\sin(x^9)$ right away due to the property $f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)$ and the region is invariant for the symmetry $(x,y)\to (-x,y).$ For the remaining integral of $x^2y$ it is convenient to apply the polar coordinates.

Comment: Your follow-up question is a totally standard exercise where you have no choice but to change the order of integration. You can find literally dozens of such problems on this site.

Comment: [$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{\sqrt x}^1\sin(\pi y^3)dydx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3978539/721644). Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to search both this site and the AoPS.